# How to get image display using React Function Component

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Can somebody take a look? the image is not displaying. keeping get error notice regarding  Thank You!

Can somebody take a look? the image is not displaying. keeping get error notice regarding  Thank You!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [catImage, setCatImage] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://aws.random.cat/meow")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCatImage(catImage);
      });
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Cat Images</h1>
      <img
        src={catImage}
        onClick={(e) => setCatImage(e.target.value)}
        alt="Cat Image"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The API is sending following:

```
{"file":"https:\/\/purr.objects-us-east-1.dream.io\/i\/UlyNwX7.jpg"}
```

so following can fix this:

```
<img
    src={catImage.file}
    onClick={(e) => setCatImage(e.target.value)}
    alt="Cat Image"
/>
```

or you can set state as:

```
setCatImage(data.file);
```

Comment: Actually `src={catImage.file}` won't fix this as there is no `catImage` set in the first place. `data` is not even used in `setCatImage`: `.then((data) => {setCatImage(catImage);})`. Can you update your answer?